How to know if new mac mini support my displays by specification?
Here are the specifications of the Apple M4 Mac mini:

Up to three displays: Two displays with up to 6K resolution at 60Hz over Thunderbolt and one display with up to 5K resolution at 60Hz over Thunderbolt or 4K resolution at 60Hz over HDMI
Up to two displays: One display with up to 5K resolution at 60Hz over Thunderbolt and one display with up to 8K resolution at 60Hz or 4K resolution at 240Hz over Thunderbolt or HDMI

I have 4 displays,  two of them are 2k 144hz, one 4k 144hz and one 4k 120hz, the specification text of the Mac mini only tells about 60hz and the resolution with it, but how about the higher refresh rate with resolutions? Is there a way to calculate if I can connect any combo of my displays?

Apple gives the specs here: https://www.apple.com/mac-mini/specs/. Scroll down to display support. With Apple it is usually the case that if a specific resolution is not mentioned it is not supported. Though there are apps available that MAY be able to work around those limitations in a limited fashion
